# regular expression to match group ending with html line break

Tags: python, regex

I have text below and I am matching group 1,2, and 3 in python regex just fine until I want to match 'me' which is between 'srcuser: ' and html line break tag. my regex is **seqno: (\d+).+?src: (\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}).+?dst: (\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}).+?srcuser: (.+)?[html line break her]**

```
domain: 1<br/>receive_time: 2017/10/25 13:47:19<br/>serial: 00790100000<br/>seqno: 7198725<br/>actionflags: 0x0<br/>type: THREAT<br/>subtype: spyware<br/>config_ver: 1<br/>time_generated: 2017/10/25 13:47:19<br/>src: 1.1.1.1<br/>dst: 2.2.2.2<br/>natsrc: 1.1.1.1<br/>natdst: 2.2.2.2<br/>rule: to INTERNET<br/>srcuser: me<br/>blabla
```

Please advise

Comment: Why o' why do you people insist on [banging your heads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) against the wall?

Comment: If you really, really must do this with regex (you don't), at least do it in multiple steps.

Comment: Using regex, although I'd suggest not to, you can use `(?:<br\s*\/>)?\s*(\w+):\s*(.*?(?=\s*<br\s*\/>|$))`. This prevents hardcoding of specific values. Use your code to determine which values you actually require based on group 1's values.

Answer (score 0):

You may give a try to:

```
seqno: (\d+).+?src: (\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}).+?dst: (\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}).+?srcuser: (.+)?<br\/>
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rm17NX/1)